# 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it' errors when adding UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7, adal

I have a web api app that implements a REST interface.  I have the service successfully running through the debugger and outside of the debugger through IIS (on localhost).

I need to add authentication to this service, and so I have added the following startup code which gets called by my startup.cs class.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureActiveDirectoryTenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    SaveSigninToken = true,
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OnboardingApplicationId"]
                }
            });
    }
}
```

This is working fine through the VS debugger as before, but when I try to access the api outside of the debugger through IIS, I get the following error:

**No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Source Error:

Line 10:         public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)

Line 11:         {

**Line 12:             app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(**

Line 13:                 new 
WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions()

Line 14:                 {

Source File:  \App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs    Line:  12

Is this a code issue or an IIS/Firewall issue?  I've added inbound and outbound rules in the firewall for the port number that the IIS site uses, but I'm pretty sure this is not the issue.

I've looked at user permissions too, so running the debugger under non-admin accounts still works.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the target machine IP? You should be able to see it from the SocketException details. I'm guessing it is the hostname or IP of your application login redirect URL. Try accessing that URL from a browser and see if it works.

Comment: Based on the error, it seems that the issue was not caused by the windows Azure Active Directory library. Was this issue fixed by removing it?

Comment: Yes, if I remove that code from my startup.cs, I don't get the exception.  So it does appear related.